# How to change one key in the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I need to change only one key in my keyboard, the key for ç, it is not used in my language nor the keyboard language so I don't know why someone would put that key there, in fact I've only seen that letter in the Portuguese language i would like to change it to something else, how can i do it?

Comment: Is there an actual key with ç printed on it, or is it another key that appears on the screen as ç?

Comment: Its another key, my keyboard layout is set to spanish, my keyboard is english, and it works fine with the exception of that key (and maybe some others too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Use this key to perform something useful like opening the calculator, or web browser or, ... by going into system settings - keyboard - shortcuts.
2. As you want to change the *standard keyboard layout* of a *standard language* in an OS with automatic updates enabled, you have to create a new language, with a new keyboard layout to be able to change <kbd>ç</kbd> to for example <kbd>%</kbd> as otherwise any update touching on the language settings of Ubuntu or keyboard layout will reset the work you've done and it'll cause you great frustration and rage... :(

(I've tried it and it's not worth trying to change the standard layout as I use ' and ` more then § and ³)

Comment: That being said: if you still want to go ahead, read [an unreliable guide to keyboard configuration](http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i decided I'm going to try and switch between languages (with sup + space) and get used to it, if i can't get used to it I might try and create a whole new language/layout.

Comment: FYI: GA is already taken, but GZ doesn't exist yet...  ;-)